# regular expressions javascript validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript code that is working:

```
<script>
function validate(form) {
    // Shortcut to save writing
    var pwd = form.elements.lgps.value;

    // Check length
    if(8 > pwd.length || pwd.length > 16)
        return false;

    // Check for at least 1 lowercase letter
    var rgx = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
    if(!rgx.test(pwd))
        return false;

    // Check for at least 1 digit
    rgx = /\d+/;
    if(!rgx.test(pwd))
        return false;

    // Check for no spaces
    rgx = /\s/;
    if(rgx.test(pwd))
        return false;

    return true;
}
</script>
```

And here's my form:

```
<form method="post" action="406.php" language="javascript" 
    name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
```

I would like to add a message alert if all the above fails, and also another field in my form to validate. So basically I have a username field and a password field.
I want the password field to be between 8 and 20 characters long, and contain at least 1 digit.

Comment: Please pay attention to the formatting help.

Comment: If you could get a version of this into jsfiddle.net, that would be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: **WHY** do you reject spaces?!?! That's kind of unacceptable for a secure password! ["correct horse battery staple" is more secure than "Tr0ub4dor"](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/427) - but only the latter would pass your check.

Comment: @ThiefMaster +1...I recently got in a heated debate over my employer's password policy with a senior IT executive over complexity != secure.  The saying "you can't teach old dogs new tricks" is only magnified with a large corporation.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine, besides the fact that the first regexp tests for uppercase and lowercase, just bracket the if statements and add

```
    alert('Password not right')
```

before the return statement.. obviously for each return you can change the alert accordingly.

Comment: and this should go with out saying but make sure you revalidate the password in your php script. It is very easy for me to send a post header to your php script with any values I want

Answer (score 0):

```
function validatePwd(form) {
    var pwd = form.elements.lgps.value;

    if(8 > pwd.length || pwd.length > 16){
        alert("Your password must be 8-16 characters in length");
        return false;
    }

    var rgx = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
    if(!rgx.test(pwd)){
        alert("Your need at least 1 lowercase letter");
        return false;
    }

    rgx = /\d+/;
    if(!rgx.test(pwd)){
        alert("You need at least 1 digit");
        return false;
    }

    rgx = /\s/;
    if(rgx.test(pwd)){
        alert("You can't have spaces");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function validateUnm(form){
    var unm = form.elements.lgem.value;

    if(3 > unm.length || unm.length > 20){
        alert("Your username must be 3-20 characters in length");
        return false;
    }

    //and more conditions....

    return true;
}
```

You would call this by:

```
<form onsubmit="validatePwd(this);validateUnm(this)">
```

Comment: thanks for the code but when i add this nothing happens.i mean you can submit the form blank. what is that //do stuff thing there?what should i enter?thanks

Comment: still same thing. maybe i have to edit something here too?<form method="post" action="406.php" language="javascript"  name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return validate(this);">

Comment: alright there you go. sorry. I didn't know that was the way your function was being called

Comment: thanks for your help. this one displays the alert and then submits the form even if anything is wrong. i don't need this exact code i can go for anything that works

Comment: give that a try... running out of options here

Comment: still the same unfortunately. if you have a different form code i'd be happy to adapt that. this one was the easiest one i could find since i'm not a javascript coder. thanks again for your time.

Comment: it only alerts if the length is not right. after that it does not submit the form, it does not check if it has 1 digit or not

Comment: works perfect!!! thanks buddy. one more thing if i may. how can i add a second field to validate?i need the username as well? thankssss

Comment: i added this var usr = form.elements.lgem.value;
 and then duplicated all elements changing their element.id

Answer (score 0):

Included below is a solution that utilizes jQuery and stores the validation requirements into an `object` named `tests`.

The value provided from the desired element, in this case the input with an ID of `pass`, is checked against the tests declared in each property.  If the test passes, then that property is set to 1 to indicate `true`.  If the test fails, then the property is set to 0 to indicate `false`.

The object is then traversed to check which properties passed and which ones failed.  If at least one test failed, then an `alert()` message is used to notify the user of the invalid criteria.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="pass" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
function validatePassword(pwd) { 
    var errors = [];

    var tests = {
        '- Min/Max Length of 8-16 characters': function(){
            return (pwd.length < 8 || pwd.length > 16 ? 0 : 1);
        }(),
        '- Contains Alpha-numeric characters': function(){
            rgx = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
            return (!rgx.test(pwd) ? 0 : 1);
        }(),
        '- Contains 1 or more Digits': function(){
            rgx = /\d+/;
            return (!rgx.test(pwd) ? 0 : 1);
        }(),
        '- Contains No Spaces': function(){
            rgx = /\s/;
            return (rgx.test(pwd) ? 0 : 1);
        }()
    };

    for(result in tests ){
        if(tests[result] == 0){
            errors.push(result);
        }
    }

    if(errors.length > 0){
                alert('Please correct your password to meet the following criteria:\n' + errors.join('\n'));
    }
}

$(function(){
    $('#pass').blur(function(){
        validatePassword($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmm6d/